# Set Cookies to HttpOnly on PrimeFaces premium theme

Tags: jsf, cookies, primefaces

I need to add HttpOnly to all the cookies on my PrimeFace project.

I have tried to set-up the cookies through the web.xml
[web.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrWgE.png)

but the cookie that is created on the layout.js [poseidon_expandeditems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPWTv.png) is created twice, once with the flag HttpOnly, but the other without it.

How can I set all the cookies created in my project to have the HttpOnly?

Comment: Sure it was not already there? And which PF version?

Comment: @Kukeltje it wasn't there... I'm using version 7.0.14 of PF

Answer (score 3):

You cannot set the cookie to be HTTP Only as that would not make it available to Javascript code.  Layout in Poseidon is creating and managing the cookie with Javascript so it must not have HTTP Only so it can manipulate the cookie.  Why do you think it needs to be HttpOnly?

from Babylon theme layout.js for example...

```js
    saveMenuState: function () {
        $.cookie('babylon_expandeditems', this.expandedMenuitems.join(','), { path: '/' });
    },

    saveScrollState: function (value) {
        $.cookie('babylon_scroll', value, { path: '/' });
    },

    clearMenuState: function () {
        $.removeCookie('babylon_expandeditems', { path: '/' });
        $.removeCookie('babylon_active_route', { path: '/' });
        $.removeCookie('babylon_static_menu_inactive', { path: '/' });
        $.removeCookie('babylon_scroll', { path:'/' });
    },
```

If you still have questions I suggest raising it on the Poseidon theme forum:
https://forum.primefaces.org/viewforum.php?f=43